How to do unit test on SoLoader.loadLibrary
I have a couple of native library that I use soLoader to load during run-time, but the dependency kept getting break during the development.
Is it possible to write a unit test against SoLoader.loadLibrary to verify that all dependency can be loaded correctly ?
